# SQL Server Management Studio: LocalDb does not show

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssms

I have SSMS 15.4, SQL Server 2019 and SQL Server 2016 LocalDB installed on my machine. I have created few databases from VS 2019 for practice projects and they all are showing fine in SQL Server Object Explorer from VS 2019 under (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB(SQL Server 13.0). When I launch SSMS and connect to a Server Name (which is my computer name) through windows authentication those databases are not listed. I am confused how to get those databases in SSMS. I have attached image through snipped in and i hope someone from the community would help me:-

From VS 2019 created databases image:

[image]

From the SSMS databases image:

[image]

Comment: LocalDB is an *on-demand* server - it will spin up when you load a given project in VS. So it's not always up and running (like the other SQL Server instances) - you can however launch it with the command-line tool `sqllocaldb` - and then you can also see it (and access it) in Management Studio .....

Comment: @marc_s I do not get your point. I have created these database files and they are pretty much physically stored in my local drive and i can see them, as you mentioned LocalDB is on on-demand-server and it wont spin up until it is not loaded in a given project in VS. Let's take an example I would not load any project in my VS but i can access these databases and run through them by SQL command in VS without having a project to load. What i don't understand is why SSMS does not load/show these created databases from the local drive.

Comment: SSMS will show files from **active** instances - LocalDB is by default **not** active. LocalDB is **NOT** an instance that's up and running all the time - like a full SQL Server instance (even Express). LocalDB is an **on-demand** instance - only when VS or your app **requests** it, then LocalDB is spun up, and then you have access to those database files. Just because you have files lying around on your disk doesn't mean, SSMS can access them - it **always** requires a **server instance** to get access to those files

Comment: @marc_s Thanks for your time and replied to my issue. I got the issue resolved by the following steps: Basically SSMS actually start by connecting to a  default server name (i.e. my computer name). What I have done was to change my server name to (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB and this connects to the localdb and i am now able to see all the databases.